# Next js doesn't update URL

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have the following component:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch';
import {Router} from '../routes';

class About extends Component {
  state = {
    results: null,
    postcode: null
  }

  handleOnChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      postcode: e.target.value
    });
  }

  handleOnSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
      // calling the api passing the postcode
      console.log(this.state.postcode)
    fetch(`http://localhost:3001/${this.state.postcode}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
          this.setState({
            results: data
          })
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error))

      Router.pushRoute('/about', {postcode: this.state.postcode})
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.results)
   return(
    <form>
      <input name="postcode" onChange={this.handleOnChange} />
      <button onClick={this.handleOnSubmit}>submit postcode</button>
    </form>
   )
  }
}

About.getInitialProps = async function(context) {
  console.log('context: ', context.query)
  return {
    results: 'data'
  }
}

export default About;
```

and my routes file like so:

```
const routes = module.exports = require('next-routes')()

routes
.add('index')
.add('about', '/about/:postcode', 'about');
```

however when I submit the form I would expect the URL to be updated with the submitted value like so:

```
http://localhost:3000/about/ => http://localhost:3000/about/postcodeValueSubmitted
```

It doesn't throw any error but the URL remains:

```
http://localhost:3000/about
```

I would need the value to be updated so that I can use 'getInitialProps' to do the server side rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
Router.pushRoute('/about', {postcode: this.state.postcode})
```

With:

```
Router.pushRoute(`/about/${this.state.postCode}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

This helped:

```
Router.pushRoute('about', {postcode: this.state.postcode})
```

note the difference without the '/'